# Trying to swap four numbers but getting 87 2 times in output

Tags: c

I am trying to swap four numbers but getting 87 2 times in output.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5;
    printf("Enter 4 Numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4);

    if ((n1 >= 72 && n1 <= 820) && 
        (n2 >= 72 && n2 <= 820) && 
        (n3 >= 72 && n3 <= 820) && 
        (n4 >= 72 && n4 <= 820))
        n4 = n1;
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = n3;
    n3 = n4;

    printf("\nAfter Interchanging n1, n2, n3 and n4 are %d %d %d %d", n1, n2, n3, n4);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter 4 Numbers: 87 98 90 76
After Interchanging n1, n2, n3 and n4 are 98 90 87 87
```

Comment: exactly what is the expected output?

Comment: `n3 = n4 = original-n1` seems to be the hitch. Look at the first and fourth assignment operation. That's ultimately what those do. Only `n4 = n1` is actually in the if-block. proper indentation would reveal that immediately.

Comment: Did you intend to have 4 assignment statements inside the `if` block?

Comment: @yano 98 90 87 76

Comment: `n1 = n2;  n2 = n3;  n3 = n4;` are not in the `if` block.

Comment: @wi yes inside the if block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n4 = n1;` erases the original value of `n4`. You will want to use another variable to save the value temporalily. Also it seems you forgot to add `{}` after the `if` statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n1, n2, n3, n4 ,n5;
    printf ("Enter 4 Numbers: ");
    scanf ("%d %d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4);

    if ((n1>=72 && n1<=820) && (n2>=72 && n2<=820)
    && (n3>=72 && n3<=820) && (n4>=72 && n4<=820)) {

        int t = n4;
        n4 = n1;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = n3;
        n3 = t;

    }

    printf ("\nAfter Interchanging n1, n2, n3 and n4 are %d %d %d %d" \
        ,n1, n2, n3, n4);

    return 0;
}
```

To obtain the output `98 90 87 76` from the input `87 98 90 76`, the swapping part

```
        int t = n4;
        n4 = n1;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = n3;
        n3 = t;
```

should be:

```
        int t = n3;
        n3 = n1;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = t;
```